# Getting connection closed prematurely when trying to send a post-request to external endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Good morning, or evening, or night.

I have been trying to send a post request to an external endpoint but keep getting " Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response". my client request pipeline looks like this

```
 public Mono<String> acquireToken() throws JsonProcessingException {
    return client.
            post()
            .uri("/login").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .body(generateLoginRequest(loginRequest), String.class)
            .acceptCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .publishOn(Schedulers.single());
}
```

as you can probably see, im not that great with reactor. Any help would be appreciated!

Have a pleasant day and hope to hear from you all!

Comment: Please see this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22464)

Comment: I have tried your solution, unfortunately I am getting the same exception as before

Comment: Does this occur everytime or only for a few requests and is the server deployed in linux or windows? Because for me, this issue occurs in windows and only when the same connection from connection pool is reused after some time..

Comment: It occurs every time, using windows for development and it is not deployed yet